# How to choose scale endpoints for` tm_fill( )`?

Tags: r, mapping

I'm trying to map a continuous scale with `tm_fill` in `tmap`:

```
tm_shape(shape)+tm_fill(col="value",pallete="seq",contrast=c(0,1)+tm_facets(by=group)
```

I want to make several such maps for different years but I want to have the scale for the fill variable to be between `0` and `1` for all of them. I thought that `contrast` would do that, but every map has a scale that ranges between minimum and maximum `value`.